# angular tests fails with unknown property on jenkins but work locally

Tags: angular

I created the following minimal example with Angular 11.

`app.component.html`

```html
<a [routerLink]="'/foobar'" *ngIf="val"></a>
```

`app.component.ts`

```js
export class AppComponent {
  val = false
}
```

and the `.spec.ts` looks like this

```js
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  it('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });

});
```

Note, I intentionally did not include the `RouterTestingModule`.

- When `val = false`, then the test passes (locally, on my windows pc).
- When `val = true`, the test still passes but I get a console error (locally, on my windows pc)

```
NG0303: Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'.
localConsole.<computed> @   context.js:265
logUnknownPropertyError @   core.js:9847
elementPropertyInternal @   core.js:9739
ɵɵproperty  @   core.js:14478
RComponent_a_0_Template @   template.html:1
executeTemplate @   core.js:9323
refreshView @   core.js:9192
```

But on my CI (jenkins) the Test ALWAYS fails (independent of `val = true|false`) with this stacktrace

> AppComponent› should create
>
> ```
> Template parse errors:
> Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("
>  ng:///DynamicTestModule/AppComponent.html@5:7
> "): ng:///DynamicTestModule/AppComponent.html@5:54
>
>   at syntaxError (../../../packages/compiler/src/util.ts:108:17)
>   at TemplateParser.Object.<anonymous>.TemplateParser.parse (../../../packages/compiler/src/template_parser/template_parser.ts:108:13)
>   at JitCompiler.Object.<anonymous>.JitCompiler._parseTemplate (../../../packages/compiler/src/jit/compiler.ts:300:33)
>   at JitCompiler.Object.<anonymous>.JitCompiler._compileTemplate (../../../packages/compiler/src/jit/compiler.ts:279:14)
>   at ../../../packages/compiler/src/jit/compiler.ts:208:42
>       at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
>   at JitCompiler.Object.<anonymous>.JitCompiler._compileComponents (../../../packages/compiler/src/jit/compiler.ts:208:15)
> ```

The strange thing is, on CI it always fails, and also the stack trace looks different from my local one. Does anyone know what could cause this?
(Note: I know that I must import the `RouterTestingModule` in the test, but currently all my tests are green locally but fail on CI which is super annoying)

Comment: Could it be that your local Angular version is different from one on the CI?

Comment: Also, do you use the same OS version on the CI runner and locally? Unfortunately, packages for windows and Linux behave differently sometimes. luckily, it happens really rare.

Comment: my CI simply does a npm install + npm run test. so the versions should be the same.

Comment: to me it looks like locally it does not use the JIT compiler but on CI it does

Comment: That could be. Which version of Angular do you use? `JitCompiler` is an old thing. Might be that its possible to avoid using it altogether

Comment: as mentioned in the OP, Angular 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I finally found the problem.

As I supposed, the unit tests did not run in ivy-mode on jenkins.
To verify, I did the following.

```
import { ɵivyEnabled as ivyEnabled } from '@angular/core';

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('> ivyEnabled', ivyEnabled);
  }
```

Locally, it returned `true`, on Jenkins it returned `false`.

To fix this, I had to adjust my `postinstall` script in `package.json`. See details here: https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/2752